# File Exist condition issue in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, file-exists

I am working on product testing automation. I am using Jenkins to create a job that will first browse some file in a directory. But I got a problem with **Conditional Step in File Exist condition**. It is not working when I search *.job file, it only works with specific file name I put. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post picture :)

Anyone can help me solve this issue. Thank so much for reading

Answer (score 0):

I don't think File Exists supports more than one file, you could try the "File match condition". Definitions below:

> **File exists** Run if the file exists.
>
> The file is expanded using the Token Macro Plugin. If the file is
>   relative, then it is relative to the Base directory. If the file is
>   absolute, then it will be tested on the Node that contains the Base
>   directory (the master for $JENKINS_HOME and Artifacts dir).
>
> **Files match** Run if one or more files match the selectors.
>
> Separate multiple includes or excludes patterns with a comma. e.g.
>   Includes "target/site/**/*.html,target/site/images/" Excludes
>   "**/*.gif" If no includes pattern is configured, then the pattern
>   "**" will be used, which matches all files in the directory and all
>   sub directories. The includes and excludes are Ant Patterns.